# Scrapy forum crawler starting but not returning any scraped data

Tags: scrapy, forum, web-crawler

Here is my code, can someone please help, for some reason the spider runs but does not actually crawl the forum threads. I am trying to extract all the text in the forum threads for the specific forum in my start url.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from xbox.items import xboxItem

from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.conf import settings


class xboxSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "xbox"
    allowed_domains = ["forums.xbox.com"]
    start_urls= [
    "http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/default.aspx",
    ]
    rules= [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/t/\d+']),callback='parse_thread'),  
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/t/new\?new_start=\d+',)))
            ]


    def parse_thread(self, response):
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item=xboxItem()
        item['content']=hxs.selec("//div[@class='post-content user-defined-markup']/p/text()").extract()
        item['date']=hxs.select("//span[@class='value']/text()").extract()
        return item
```

Log output:

```
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [xbox] INFO: Spider opened 
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [xbox] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023 
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/f/…; (referer: None) 
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'forums.xbox.com': <GET forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/f/…; 
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] INFO: Dumping spider stats
```

Comment: show us your crawler log ..

Comment: 2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [xbox] INFO: Spider opened
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [xbox] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-03-13 11:22:18-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080

Comment: 2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/f/310.aspx> (referer: None)
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'forums.xbox.com': <GET http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/f/310/t/283312.aspx>
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-03-13 11:22:20-0400 [xbox] INFO: Dumping spider stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first tweak, you need to modify your first rule by putting a "." at the start of the regex, as follows. I also changed the start url to the actual first page of the forum.

```
start_urls= [
"http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/e_k/gearsofwar3/f/310.aspx",
]
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('./t/\d+')), callback="parse_thread", follow=True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('./310.aspx?PageIndex=\d+')), ),
    )
```

I've updated the rules so that the spider now crawls all of the pages in the thread.

EDIT: I've found a typo that may be causing an issue, and I've fixed the date xpath.

```
 item['content']=hxs.selec("//div[@class='post-content user-defined-markup']/p/text()").extract()
 item['date']=hxs.select("(//div[@class='post-author'])[1]//a[@class='internal-link view-post']/text()").extract()
```

The line above says "hxs.selec" and should be "hxs.select". I changed that and could now see content being scraped. Through trial and error (I'm a bit rubbish with xpaths), I've managed to get the date of the first post (ie the date the thread was created) so this should all work now.

Comment: I didn't check that far. If you're not getting any scraped output, then that points at your xpaths being wrong. You can test them out by calling "scrapy shell xbox" and then trying out different xpaths by typing "hxs.select(EXAMPLE_XPATH)".

Comment: yea I am thinking it's def the xpath, I ran the shell yesterday but I am going to dig a little deeper..Thanks..this forum has some serious layers of html :/ but the results are worth it :)

Comment: Fixed the xpath for date (see my edited answer above). On a different note, are you getting Judgement when it comes out? :)

Comment: yes I got the dates to all come out the xpath for the forum text is a bit tricky..xpath is such a pain.. Yes I am doing sentiment analysis research :)

Comment: seems to be a problem with my CrawlSpider too, once I use Base dates are all set

Comment: So I got the xpath and all is good for my Base Spider just need to figure how to crawl the damn thing, here we go :) works like a charm! I'll post when stackoverflow lets me in a few hours